# Simplest case of Langlands-Shahidi method

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, eisenstein-series

I would like to read the simplest examples of Langlands-Shahidi method carried out to prove the functional equation of $L$-function.

Could the constant term of $\mathrm{GL}(2)$-Eisenstein series be used to prove the functional equation of $L$-functions? (standard on $\mathrm{GL}(2)$ or Rankin-Selberg on $\mathrm{GL}(2) \times \mathrm{GL}(2)$ or adjoint/symmetric square on $\mathrm{GL}(2)$)

Answer (score 5):

I think that the best introduction to the Langlands-Shahidi method still is the following book by Shahidi and Gelbart:

- Gelbart & Shahidi, "*Analytic Properties of Automorphic L-Functions*" (1988)

It includes a detailed exposition of the $\mathrm{GL}(2)×\mathrm{GL}(2)$ case, from both the Langlands-Shahidi and the Rankin-Selberg point of view (and the relation between them). Of course, general $\mathrm{GL}(n)×\mathrm{GL}(m)$ and symmetric powers are also treated.

As for your other questions, yes, those examples of L-functions are well covered by this method, see the list [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=jb3ZCp0-MQsC&pg=PR12&lpg=PR12&dq=lectures+automorphic+L+functions+cogdell&source=bl&ots=7BTs3tsrUF&sig=HMEcLfcrC9W2aZadAbinMIfU39g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DgbXU9-sO8ucyASlzYGoBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=list%20langlands%20shahidi%20l-functions&f=false).